# repeat the play of the music certain x number of time using android media player

Tags: android, loops, for-loop, android-mediaplayer

In my application user selects the count like 1, 21, 51, 101, 108,like when he selected using buttons or radio button, the media player has to be repeated at number of time. If he selects 21, media player should repeat the playing of the music by 21 times. In my code, if I use while loop inside the for loop its blocking the UI, not allowing to stop or pause the play, if I did not use the while loop it plays only once. Please I need to solve it any one will be appreciated thanks in advance. Below I am posting my entire code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    int count;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        findViewById(R.id.button_1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_3).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_4).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_5).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.pause).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            if (mp!=null) {
                mp.release();
            }

            player(3);

            break;
        case R.id.button_2:
            if (mp!=null) {
                mp.release();
            }
            player(21);

            break;
        case R.id.button_3:
            if (mp!=null) {
                mp.release();
            }
            player(51);

            break;
        case R.id.button_4:
            if (mp!=null) {
                mp.release();
            }
            player(108);

            break;
        case R.id.button_5:
            if (mp!=null) {
                mp.release();
            }

            break;
        case R.id.pause:

                mp.pause();


            break;
        case R.id.stop:

                mp.stop();


            break;

        }


    }

    private void player(int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);

         for (int i=1; i<=count ; i++){
             mp.start();
             while(mp.isPlaying());
     }
        // mp.release();





 }  
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(null!=mp){
            mp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve this by setting a yourCount integer that has the numbers you are going to repeat your sound and than simply do this

```
    int count = 0;
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (count < yourCount) {
                mp.start();
                count++;
            }
        }
    });
    mp.start();
```

Comment: where do i want to implement it in on create or in the switch condition in my code.

Comment: in the player method where you are playing your music

Comment: OnCompletionListener can not be resolved error is coming

Comment: loop is taking infinite

Comment: yes thanks it works for me after replacing some variable proper declaration its worked thanks

Comment: Does it place a gap between loops?

Answer (score 3):

try this, Hope it helps

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){

```
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Count here and restart if required.
    }});
```